# How do i Modifying isEnabled property of WPF Button from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Am trying to enable the button which is not changing, Am using this WPF project in another Web application. Below is my code.

```
  this.btnChkOut.IsEnabled = true;
   MessageBox.Show(btnChkOut.IsEnabled.ToString());

<Button IsEnabled="False" ToolTipService.ToolTip="CheckOut" x:Name="btnChkOut"      Opacity="1" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="2"
                     Click="btnChkOut_Click">Check Out
```

Comment: that's not clear ? what are your trying to do here ?

Comment: all works fine at my end tell us wat u doing

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a Binding instead.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="CheckOut" x:Name="btnChkOut"      Opacity="1" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="2"
                     Click="btnChkOut_Click">

public bool IsButtonEnabled { get; set; }
```

Comment: This WPF project is loaded to a div within web Application, So if a user gives Checkout we enable that button.Initially all buttons will be disabled , so based on the input given from web application,we change the isEnabled property.

Comment: But whatever I give , the IsEnabled Property is not reflecting, its false always.

Comment: well its a simple scenario and I have tested it just now it works, to explain you further you need to show us code on where you are changing the isenabled and when it is called..

Comment: Even while running this WPF as a seperate project , the code is working fine. But if i use this within web page , i dont know what is going wrong.

Comment: is the parent of your button enabled ?

Comment: Ya its enabled, sometimes its getting enabled. IS there any way to refresh or update the button.

Comment: when you set isEnabled = true, it will refresh automatically provided parent is enabled.

Comment: Take a break.. relax !